# How to check which tracked files are currently gitignore'd/non-gitignore'd?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have modified my `.gitignore` file to keep it cleaner, but I expect it has the same behaviour than previously and I would like to check that it would not ignore any of my already tracked files (if they were not tracked).

How can I check it? Is there some way to list the tracked files that would be covered by the current `.gitignore` rules (so ideally this list would be empty)?

Thanks!

Comment: files that are tracked are not affected by `.gitignore`.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes, I know, I meant they wouldn't be covered by the gitignore rules if they were not be tracked.

Answer (score 5):

Once you already have some tracked files, and then you add them to `gitignore` file, `git` will not forget about them. So you need to explicitly untrack them, as described in this thread - [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore).

And overall, you could list all ignored file using this command (https://gist.github.com/naholyr/1836765#file-git-ignored-sh)

```
git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard
```

Comment: This works great for files only. Is there a way to do this for folders as well?
edit: just needed to add --directory to the end of the command.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display all files in the repo which are ignored (but, as eftshift0 rightfully notes, are therefore *not* tracked), you can do

```
$ git ls-files -oi --exclude-standard
```

Comparing what you get from that command alternatively with your old and new `.gitignore` files can be a good troubleshooting step. Also note that you can `git check-ignore -v <path/to/some/file>` to debug some specific file and see where the ignoring comes from (in case of multiple nested ignore files)